# Solution of the binary to integer code through stream api explanation

Tags: java, java-8

On solving a kata on codewars I came across a single line solution to the problem of converting a binary number (in the form of a list ) to integer.
I am unable to understand the solution where people have used java stream api reduce function.Please help me understand it.

Eg: [0, 0, 0, 1] is treated as 0001 which is the binary representation of 1.

```
import java.util.List;

public class BinaryArrayToNumber {

    public static int ConvertBinaryArrayToInt(List<Integer> binary) {
       return binary.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x * 2 + y).get();
 }
}
```

Comment: Only 1 binary number is stored in List ? Or every object of Integer contain a binary number?

Comment: only 1 binary number

Comment: This solution is wrong, it only works for sequential streams and it's violating `Stream.reduce`'s contract, which mandates that the function must be associative (`(x, y) -> x * 2 + y` clearly isn't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the math behind it is based on the method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Decimal)

The working of the code is best understood with the help of an example. Consider a binary number 1011 (Decimal 11)

- The operation is streamed sequentially . From the way the reduce operation behaves we'll rename `x` as `accumulator` and `y` as `ele`
- We can now state the above operation mathematically as

  `accumulator = (accumulator*2)+ ele`     // [refer here for why](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-)
- Lets run the formula on 1011
- Streaming begins with the first element i.e the left side and goes sequentially
- start: accumulator = 0
- 1) accumulator = (0 * 2) + 1   //first element,  accumulator = 1
- 2) accumulator = (1 * 2) + 0   //second element, accumulator = 2
- 3) accumulator = (2 * 2) + 1   //third element,  accumulator = 5
- 4) accumulator = (5 * 2) + 1   //last element,   accumulator = 11

You can extend this to n binary digits.

One important thing to note is that although this is okay for coding competitions, this should never be used in a real world appication as the `reduce()` expects an associative operation and also gives no guarantees of running sequentially

Comment: What does .get() do?

Comment: get() is a method in [`java.util.Optional`] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) , its used to denote that there may or may not be a value present. Its like a safe alternative to using `null` in your code. Over here, if you were to run the function on an empty `List` then you would end up with a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` denoting no values were there to process in the first place, otherwise it will return the result.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the reduce function is to accumulate the elements from the stream into a single result, using the given formula.

This accumulation process is done repeatedly for each element of the stream. Initially, 1st argument("x") takes 0, and the 2nd argument("y") takes first value from the stream. For each subsequent step, the result from the previous calculation will be used as the 1st argument, and the next value from the stream will be used as the 2nd argument.

Using procedural programming, **return binary.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x * 2 + y).get();** in your case would be equivalent to the following snippet:

```
int x = 0;
for(int y : binary) {
    x = x * 2 + y;
}
return x;
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` essentially enables one to "reduce" (also known as *fold*, *accumulate*) the streams elements into a *single* value.

---

You don't need to look any further than the [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method documentation to find out the exact steps taken:

it provides an example saying it's equivalent to:

```
boolean foundAny = false;
T result = null;
for (T element : this stream) {
     if (!foundAny) {
         foundAny = true;
         result = element;
     }
     else
         result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
}
return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
```

where `accumulator` is the function you've supplied i.e. `(x, y) -> x * 2 + y`

Comment: But only for sequential streams. Since `(x, y) -> x * 2 + y` is not an associative function, it’s abusing `reduce` for a left-fold (which the Stream API does not offer). Executed in parallel, this solution could produce wrong numbers.

Comment: @Holger I think that comment would be more appropriate to the OP under their post rather than the code I've shown :).